# Why doesn't buy at open get the official open price?

Tags: trading, day-trading

Every day, a stock or ETF has an official open price, like its high, low, and close prices.  If I put in a market-buy-at-open order, whether well before the open (overnight) or just a minute or two before the open, I sometimes get the official open price, but often not, sometimes by a significant amount.  Apparently the open price is set by the open auction, aka opening cross, but the official open price is from the first trade of the day after the market opens.  If I sell at close, I (almost) always get the official close price, but not so for the open.  Anyone know why, or how to get the official open price consistently?

**Edit:** For reference, the auction I'm talking about is described here:

- https://www.nyse.com/publicdocs/nyse/markets/nyse-arca/NYSE_Arca_Auctions_Brochure.pdf
- http://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/091113/auction-method-how-nyse-stock-prices-are-set.asp
- http://www.itg.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/MOOandMOC_11_6_09.pdf
- http://www.itg.com/news_events/papers/Inside_Opening_Auction.pdf
- http://blog.themistrading.com/2010/03/new-nyse-closing-auction-rules-begin-today-opening-and-closing-nasdaq-and-nyse-cheat-sheet/

And the questions I'm trying to resolve are related to
http://www.elitetrader.com/et/index.php?threads/where-can-i-check-nyse-opening-auction-prices.286797/

Comment: The answer here is clearly wrong. I wonder if you ever resolved this question?

Comment: Given that the original poster's points are still showing as 61, and that they concluded they weren't going to get an answer they liked here, it's almost certain they are no longer using their Stack Exchange account so they are unlikely to respond to your inquiry. As far as whether the answer is correct or not: if you can show where the error is, that would help us all learn... Or might help you understand where your error is.

Comment: I think the point of the question is that the "official open price" is actually determined by an auction based on the orders in the system at the open time, so the OP is confused about why their orders don't actually seem to participate in the auction and hence trade at that price. From reading references like https://www.nyse.com/markets/nyse-american/trading-info, I *think* it's because the auction price is set to maximise volume and not necessarily clear all orders, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Order time and price determines who gets what and when.

Comment: They might not trade at that price if everyone willing to accept that price or higher has sold before everyone willing to buy at that price or lower has bought. If the stock happens to be rising at that moment, bidding at a price that doesn't reflect that rise means standing toward the end of the line of people hoping to get shares. That may be sufficient explanation. This obviously isn't an issue for those of us who buy or sell at market rate rather than trying to micro-optimize every single transaction -- in other words, those of us who are investing rather than day-trading. [Fixing error]

Comment: I think you still haven't addressed the point of the opening auction (described in the link I gave). The *exchange* runs that auction and tries to find some price according to its own rules based on the orders that were submitted prior to the open. It's not a standard order book situation where a market order is just picking off the best bid or ask currently available.

Comment: By coincidence, Matt Levine's Money Stuff describes the opening auction today: https://www.bloomberg.com/opinion/articles/2023-01-25/nyse-forgot-to-open-yesterday

Answer (score 5):

There is no official price. There is only the price a seller is willing to offer and a buyer is willing to accept at that moment. It tends to be close to the price negotiated for the last such sale, but that's just market statistics, not anything actively managed or guaranteed. "Past performance is no guarantee of future results;" this buyer and seller may not agree with the previous pair. Especially when the market has been closed overnight but real-world events have continued to occur.

Remember, this is effectively an auction with many near-but-not-quite-simultaneous bidders. Your odds of being both the high bidder and the first to offer that price are pretty darned low unless you are offering to overpay. The opening price is the auctioneer's initial ask, and the market then counters with bids which may be higher, lower, or the same... But the opening will rarely be the best price offered for that first transaction, and the moment any transaction takes place people may adjust their offers or asks.

Late thought: I think the real problem here is that an abstraction -- "opening price", used for reporting the day's change in price and related statistics -- is being mistaken for an actual price someone has offered to sell and/or buy at. And further being mistaken for a price which is would be meaningful for more than the very first transaction, possibly the very first share, if it *was* real.

Comment: If you go to any of the financial sites, you will find that ABC opened at $x.yz, just as it had a high, low, and close price.  The open price is set by an auction process before the open.  I'm afraid your answer does not address my question.

Comment: You can't get that "official open price" unless someone is willing to sell for that price or less. As far as I know, it is _entirely_ a statistical fiction intended only as a suggested/best-guess starting point so folks can factor it into their plans. It is not in any way a guaranteed or enforced price.

Comment: @AlbertLeo This answer does in fact address your question, assuming you know the technical definition of a "market" order.  A market order means you're asking your broker to get the best price it can, but (a) your broker might be slower than other market participants, and (b) even if they're fast that best price might be several ticks away from the published opening price.  Please see some of the "Related" questions in the right-hand margin for more information on how stock market matching engines work.

Comment: (One of the drawbacks of tablet app is that it doesn't display Related suggestions. Grump(ish).

Comment: Sorry I wasted my time here.

Comment: @albertLeo: Feel free to clarify your question, eg by providing a description of (and citation for) the process you believe should produce a different result than the one I've described. I have to believe that either you misunderstood something or whoever you gave you the information about the "auction process" misunderstood something.... or there's something I misunderstood, in which case I'd be glad to learn more. Also, there's always the chance that someone else will post another answer that clarifies the misunderstanding. You've only "wasted your time" if you don't let the process finish.

Comment: https://www.nyse.com/publicdocs/nyse/markets/nyse-arca/NYSE_Arca_Auctions_Brochure.pdf

Comment: http://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/091113/auction-method-how-nyse-stock-prices-are-set.asp

Comment: http://www.itg.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/MOOandMOC_11_6_09.pdf

Comment: http://www.itg.com/news_events/papers/Inside_Opening_Auction.pdf

Comment: http://blog.themistrading.com/2010/03/new-nyse-closing-auction-rules-begin-today-opening-and-closing-nasdaq-and-nyse-cheat-sheet/

Comment: I buy and sell at open every day, for the last six years.

Comment: This is the kind of issue I am trying to understand.   http://www.elitetrader.com/et/index.php?threads/where-can-i-check-nyse-opening-auction-prices.286797/

Comment: I believe you are misinterpreting the documents -- i don't think they apply to your transaction -- but since I'm not 110% certain i'm going to leave this for someone else to answer.

Comment: Took the liberty of editing these into your question. Comments on SE don't always persist, and a self-contained question is more useful for future readers.